# Play scala unit test with JUnitRunner and Specification

Tags: scala, junit, playframework-2.1

Im running test on my play framework with scala.
I have a scala class with some tests, they all go like this:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class UpdateProductTest extends Specification   
{
  abstract class WithDbData extends WithApplication {
  }
    "Product DB Repository" should
    {
      //This is test #1 !
      "add product with minimal fields" in  new WithDbData
      {
        val name =  Some(LocalizedItem(IdGenerator.newId, "testName"))
        val description =  Some(LocalizedItem(IdGenerator.newId, "testDescription"))
        val product = new Product(Option(IdGenerator.newId), "defaultTestName", "defaultTestDescription",
      Some(1), None, None, None,
      None, new References(Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1")), None, None,
      name,description, None)
        val productRepository = new ProductDbRepositoryImpl() 
        productRepository.addProduct("en_US", "1", product)
      }
    }

  "Product DB Repository" should  // <= i wish to run only this test and ignore the test above!!
    {
      val image1:ProductImage = new ProductImage(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString, Some("high resultion"), Some("url to image 1"), Some(1))
      val image2:ProductImage = new ProductImage(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString, Some("low resolution"), Some("url to image 2"), Some(1))

      //This is test #2 !
  "add product with minimal fields and images" in  new WithDbData
  {  
              .....
      }
```

My problem is all tests start with **should**  will run, **I only want to run test #2 in this class** - How do i do it ??

Thanks!